Pass generated C++ struct templates to a C header
See also "How can I pass an object of a C++ class to/from a C function?" (C++ FAQ), however I am unsure how to apply it to my case.
I'm trying to expose C-compatible types (structs) from my C++ source file.
I made them theoretically compatible by "casting" the struct to different ways. How do I make those "casted" types accessible to by C header c_header.h?
cpp_header.hpp
#ifdef __cplusplus

template <typename T>
struct item {
    uint32_t foo;
    T data;
};

int bar(struct item<T> *item);

extern "C" {

typedef struct item<uint8_t> u8_item_t;
typedef struct item<uint16_t> u16_item_t;

}

#endif // __cplusplus

c_header.h
#include "cpp_header.hpp"

int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item);
int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item);


cpp_source.cpp
#include "cpp_header.hpp"
#include "c_header.h"

template <typename T>
int bar(struct item<T> *item) {
    // ...
    return 0;
}

extern "C" {

int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item) { return bar<uint8_t>(item); }
int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item) { return bar<uint16_t>(item); }

}

When compiling, the first errors I see are
c_header.h : error: unknown type name 'u8_item_t'
   | int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item);
                ^~~~~~~~~
c_header.h : error: unknown type name 'u16_item_t'
   | int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item);
                 ^~~~~~~~~


There are no casts here. C doesn't have templates, you can't make C accept templates through any means.

c_header.h's int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item); in the error message doesn't match the c_header.h content. Please provide a [mre].

Now they match after the edit. See the first comment.

My bad, I corrected to what I originally had in my code, errors due to copy-paste and simplifications of the example

So there is no way I can have a C-compatible u8_item_t derived from the cpp template item ?

Your idea with strict u8_item_t *item in c_header.h would be good if you remove #include and extern "C" in .cpp.

Thank you for the direction, but didn't seem to help given that c_header.h isn't aware of the type definition u8_item_t. Is this a case where one has to pass a void* to the cpp function bar<uint8_t> which then casts it to item<uint8_t>* ?

Your "cpp_header.hpp" lacks #else part. It should be something like in your example FAQ link. Declare opaque u8_item_t and u16_item_t struct types in it.

u8_item_t is not C-compatible. Assumption that wrapping something into extern "C" makes it C-compatible is wrong. For C header you'll have to define a separate structure for each member type instead of including CPP header with templates.

The problem is that your typedefs for the C types are inside the C++ guard. Unfortunately, if you move them outside, you will get an error any time your are compiling C, because C does not have template types.
Probably your best choice is just to define C incomplete types. You will also need a separate C function for each variant of your template type you use because C can't tell the difference  -they are all pointers and it also doesn't have parameter overloading.
#ifdef __cplusplus

template <typename T>
struct item {
    uint32_t foo;
    T data;
};

int bar(struct item<T> *item);

extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct u8_item_t u8_item_t;
typedef struct u16_item_t u16_item_t;

int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item);
int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif // __cplusplus

bar_u8 and bar_u16 are shim functions and their only purpose is to do the cast and call the template function.

Friendly reminder that int bar(struct item<T> *item); is bizarre.

@PasserBy Actually, it's incorrect syntax isn't it? I try to avoid C++ so my knowledge of template definitions is sketchy.

It is correct, even for templates (see "elaborated type specifier" here). struct is mandatory in C while optional in C++, but since the type is a template, the code looks like neither.

@PasserBy how would you suggest to have it? int bar(item<T> *item); ?

I have found a way to resolve my problem thanks feedback from @PasserBy and @ÖöTiib
I started to mix the C++ and C code into one header file that can be included in either C or C++. I would be interested to know if this is a good idea or not (I'm obviously new to the C++ side ^^)
c(pp)_header.h
#ifdef __cplusplus

template <typename T>
struct item {
    uint32_t foo;
    T data;
};

typedef item<uint8_t> u8_item_t;
typedef item<uint16_t> u16_item_t;

#else // __cplusplus

// Opaque definitons for C
typedef struct u8_item u8_item_t;
typedef struct u16_item u16_item_t;

#endif // __cplusplus


#ifdef __cplusplus

template <typename T>
int bar(item<T> *item){
    // ...
    return 0;
}

extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus

int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item);
int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

I didn't know about the limitations of templates for multi-file usage. which meant I had to put all the declarations in the .hpp and the C implementations in the .cpp
cpp_source.cpp
#include "c(pp)_header.h"

int bar_u8(u8_item_t *item) { return bar<uint8_t>(item); }
int bar_u16(u16_item_t *item) { return bar<uint16_t>(item); }


